# Filter in Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form and I want it to be filtered just after it loads.

After I click on the form it should be able to load by filtering specific data.
I want it to filter by Program Nam and Year.

I have tried the following code but I keep getting syntax errors:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Combo5.Value = Form_0_Cover.Combo0
Combo7.Value = Form_0_Cover.Combo2

'Me.Filter = "[Program_Name]=" & Me.Combo7 & " AND [Budget_Year]='" & Me.Combo5 & ""



End Sub
```

I am not sure what the problem seems to be. I keep getting syntax error.

Comment: Is the Budget_year defined as text or a number?

Comment: Budgert Year is Number and Program Name is Text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Me.Filter = "[Program_Name]='" & Me.Combo7 & "' AND [Budget_Year]=" & Me.Combo5
```

I suspect that program name is text and budget year is numeric. It is possible that the program name combo has an id as the bound column, in which case things might get a little more difficult, probably:

```
Me.Filter = "[Program_ID]=" & Me.Combo7 & " AND [Budget_Year]=" & Me.Combo5
```

Comment: When I tried "Me.Filter = "[Program_Name]='" & Me.Combo7 & "' AND [Budget_Year]=" & Me.Combo5 " It asked me for a Parameter value for Budget Year

Comment: Then use the right name. Is it called `Budget Year` or `Budget_Year`? Look at the table or query.

Comment: It is Budget_Year and that is what I used

Comment: there are no syntax errors. although it only filters by Program Name not Year. If I select 2011 and "Test" as a program name or 2012 and test..the same data appears

Comment: What is the record source for your form?

Comment: The name of the form which is "1_Supportive_Housing"

Comment: In design view for forms properties under Record Source is says "1_Supportive_Housing"? Is this the name of a table or query? Does it have a field (column) called Budget_Year?

Comment: Yes. The name of the table is also the same: "1_Supportive_Housing" and it does contain Budget_Year as one of the fields...which is a Number

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12511/discussion-between-remou-and-ish)