# Find a record based on info selected in two separate combo boxes

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a form with about 1200 records. I would like to have the user select a value from a combo box and then select a value from a second combo box. I have a button, and when it is clicked I would like the database to find the record that corresponds to what was selected in the combo boxes.

Is there any easy way to do this? Programming is not a skill of mine, so all I could really come up with was going to the macro builder for `on click` and selecting the `SearchForRecord` option. And then for the `Where Condition` I put 
`[Field1]=[Combo1] and [Field2]=[Combo2]` but that does not seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter in Access form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022729/filter-in-access-form)

Comment: Need to concatenate variables. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html